# Average rain for 7 days

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Assuming that Average rain rained for 7 days is 7 cm.
First 6 days's average rain rained is 6 cm, then how much is rain rained on the 7th day of the week?

Comment: This is just an equation, nothing special :(

Comment: Please do not ask your homework questions on puzzling.SE.

Answer (score 2):

It's:

> 13cm.
>  First 6 days averaged 6cm so 36 cm of rain fell.
>  Need 49cm for 7 day average of 7cm.
>  $49 - 36 = 13$